# Why BROADCAST receiver registration causing error. My app just crashing because of this "android:exported="true"

Tags: android, broadcast

If i remove this "android:exported="true"" or make it FALSE, then BroadCast receiver does not work. :-/
How to solve this error, while me trying to perform some action on receiving SMS !!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pucit.arsh_hp.multisms">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"    
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action     android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" android:enabled="true" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to keep `android:exported="true"`, because this enables your broadcast receiver to listen to events triggered *outside* your application.

> android:exported
>   Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and "false" if not. If "false", the only messages the broadcast receiver can receive are those sent by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID.
>   The default value depends on whether the broadcast receiver contains intent filters. The absence of any filters means that it can be invoked only by Intent objects that specify its exact class name. This implies that the receiver is intended only for application-internal use (since others would not normally know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the broadcast receiver is intended to receive intents broadcast by the system or other applications, so the default value is "true".
>
> This attribute is not the only way to limit a broadcast receiver's external exposure. You can also use a permission to limit the external entities that can send it messages (see the permission attribute).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#exported

You crash must be related to your code processing the data received by your BroadcastReceiver, and not caused by the BroadcastReceiver itself.